# How to fill a List<CustomObject> with variables taken from a List<Integer> in a loop?

Tags: java, list, loops, object, arraylist

I have a list of Integers as

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

of numbers taken from a database (this list contains 46 different numbers) and I have to fill a list of custom objects as

```
List<CustomObject> listNumber2 = new ArrayList<CustomObject>;
```

CustomObject is:

```
public class CustomObject {
    private int DBIndex;
    private double value;
    //Getters and Setters follow
}
```

I used this piece of code to fill `listNumber2`:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
CustomObject temp = new CustomObject();
for(Integer i:lista) {
    temp.setDBIndex(i);
    System.out.print("Insert value for index no. " + i + " --> ");
    temp.setValue(input.nextDouble());
    listNumber2.add(temp);
}
```

To check the values I printed `list` before filling `listNumber2` and it was all OK, then filled it and printed it: it was 46(`listNumber2.size()`) times the last value of `DBIndex` and 46 times the last value of `value`...
I tried to change one or two little things but it was all the same, then started the debugger.
The tab `Variables` stated (`v` and `>` as arrows):

```
  Name               |    Value
v list               |    ArrayList<E> (id=38)
    v elementData    |    Object[49] (id=42)
        v [0]        |    Integer(id=43)
            value    |    10
        > [1]        |    Integer(id=47)
        > [2]        |    Integer(id=48)
        > ...        |    ...
    > modCount       |    46
    > size           |    46
v listNumber2        |    ArrayList<E> (id=15)
    v elementData    |    Object[10] (id=41)
        v [0]        |    CustomObject (id=36)
            DBIndex  |    79
            value    |    4.45
        v [1]        |    CustomObject (id=36)
            DBIndex  |    79
            value    |    4.45
        > [2]        |    CustomObject (id=36)
        > ...        |    ...
    v modCount       |    46
    v size           |    46
```

Every time, during the debug, it passed the instruction `temp.setDBIndex(i);` every `DBIndex` of `listNumber2` changed into the new `i` of the `for` loop and the new value of the `Scanner` filled every `value` overwriting the previous one, after `temp.setValue(input.nextDouble());`, so, in the end, every object in the list has the same values. Furthermore, as you can se in the variables section, every object in the list has the same id, like it was copied.
How is it even possible? Is there any alternative option for me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating 46 instances of CustomObject you adding same object 46 times - so when you changing it in loop it changes for all references which actually pointing to same object in memory. 
The solution is to move `CustomObject temp = new CustomObject();` into for loop.

Answer (score 0):

try to put the initialization of the CustomObject in the loop because the listNumber2 has to contain separate objects.